# SCP and SSH connect, but FileZilla and CyberDuck can't

Tags: ssh, scp, sftp, filezilla, cyberduck

I'm on a Mac. I'm trying to connect to a remote Ubuntu server.

I can successfully connect to it using ssh and scp commands in the shell. For example:

```
$ scp -i ~/Projects/keys/foo.pem foo_config.ini root@foo.com:/var/
foo_config.ini                                                                                                                                                      100%   15KB  14.7KB/s   00:00
```

However, I get errors when I try to connect on SFTP using the same public key in either FileZilla or CyberDuck.

I get an SSH_FXP_INIT error in CyberDuck:
[image: SSH_FXP_INIT error]

I get exitcode 127 in FileZilla:

```
Status: Connecting to foo.com...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    keyfile "/bar/foo.ppk"
Command:    open "root@foo.com" 22
Status: Connected to foo.com
Error:  Connection closed by server with exitcode 127
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

FileZilla converted the .pem to .ppk format. The permissions on the .pem are 600. The permissions on the .ppk are 700.

I can connect to a different server that shares the same key in CyberDuck. It's just this specific server which is giving me trouble. I've connected to this server successfully in the past using WinSCP on Windows, but I'm on a Mac now.

I've tried configuring CyberDuck to use SCP instead of SFTP, but I'm still getting the same error.

Is there something I need to change about the server configuration?